# ¿Listas asociativas en Python?

Tags: python

En Python por lo que tengo entendido, lo más parecido a los arrays son las `listas` y los `tuples`. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de que al menos, al introducir un nuevo dato en una lista, le puedas dar un nombre, como si fuese un array asociativo. De esa forma cuando necesite usar esa información lo buscaría por el nombre que le he dado y no por la posición dentro de la lista, algo que puede variar.

De momento sólo uso listas en Python:

```
info_juego = []

info_juego.append(dato)
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas un diccionario en su lugar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si deseas acceder a un elemento mediante una clave en un iterables entonces debes usar un diccionario, por ejemplo:

```
>>> d = {"key1": 100}
>>> d["key2"] = 5  # guarda el valor 5 con la clave key2
>>> print(d["key1"])  # accedemos a 100 mediante la clave key1
100
>>> print(d["key2"]) # accedemos a 5 mediante la clave key2
5
```

Comment: ¡Gracias! No había dado con esta posibilidad.